# Is this transformation even possible using an Dataraptor?

Tags: omnistudio, vlocity

Ive tried and failed so now just wanting to confirm with those that know better - is this transformation even possible using a Transform Dataraptor (which Ive been asked to use), or do I just revert to far more efficient Apex?

I need to transform this array of objects :

```
{ "Data" : [{
            "Name":"a",
            "Type":"t1",
            "Size":"s"
        },
        {
            "Name":"b",
            "Type":"t1",
            "Size":"s"
        },
        {
            "Name":"c",
            "Type":"t1",
            "Size":"s"
        }]}
```

into the following single object, where the Name of each array entry is used to create a unique node:

```
{ "Data": 
            {
                "a":{
                    "Type":"t1",
                    "Size":"s"
                },
                "b":{
                    "Type":"t1",
                    "Size":"s"
                },
                "c":{
                    "Type":"t1",
                    "Size":"s"
                }
            }
        }
```

any thoughts are most appreciated!

Comment: The new strcuture would mandate that you know the properties (ie a,b,c...). Is that always the case? How would it account for when there are more than 3 elements in your original array?

Comment: This is not possible in using data transform only as the name can be anything dynamic and the result needs to have this dynamic name as a key. thus I would suggest to use a simple apex and call from Integration procedure, and do the transformation logic in apex.

Comment: Thanks for response. I agree. Unfortunately client wont permit apex - apparently omnistudio can do it all lol.

Answer (score 1):

There are Salesforce documentation [here](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.os_manipulate_json_with_the_send_response_transformations_properties_22367.htm&type=5) which shows how to reparent the node dynamically using merge field syntax.

Using the logic in the mentioned documentation, you can create an Integration Procedure which transforms each list entry to its desired form.
High level steps include:

1. Get value of `Name` node for the relevant list
2. Transform List entry to only have the required key:value pairs
3. Assign the retrieved value of the `Name` node as the new node name for the transformed list entry

This will basically transform a list entry:

```
{
    "Name": "a",
    "Type": "t1",
    "Size": "s"
}
```

to the required format of:

```
{
  "a": {
    "Size": "s",
    "Type": "t1"
  }
}
```

I found it easiest to use the Integration Procedure in another Integration Procedure.
This was purely to make debugging easier, as I prefer little chunks rather than one big thing.

The parent Integration Procedure has a loop element that loops over all the list entries and builds the new list as it goes.
I ended up with the required format but it went from `c` to `a` which I assume is not a problem as you can easily get the values you want by using merge field syntax such as `Data:a` or `Data:c`.

You can download the Datapack [here](https://github.com/sfadriaan/Stack-Exchange-Answers/tree/main/411024) to play around with.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

In general, whether you're using a dataraptor or some other components within an integration procedure, Vlocity does not support dynamic key assignment. Values can be assigned to pre defined keys using variables, however you can't use variables to define object keys.

The transformation you want to achieve requires the value stored in "Name" key to be used as the new object key, which is a case of dynamic key assignment.

Note : You can easily achieve this transformation using an apex class. Use Remote Action to execute apex from an Integration Procedure.